# how to find rows in numpy array thatare in another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np 
arrlist = np.array([[1,0,0,1] , [0,1,1,0]])
rng = np.random.default_rng()
rand_arr = rng.choice([0, 1], size=(5, 4)))
```

How do I find the indices `i` of every row in `rand_arr` where `rand_arr[i]` is in `arrlist`?

For example, `rand_arr` maybe -

`rand_arr = np.array([[1,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0]])`

So the expected return value should be -

`np.array([[0,1]])`

note all the above values `rand_arr` and `arrlist` are only known at runtime.

Comment: In the interest of asking a complete question with a reproducible example, you should hardcode a value for `rand_arr` for your question, and show the output you expect for that value.

Answer (score 2):

Use broadcasting to compare each row of `arrlist` to `rand_arr`, then aggregate along the rows, then `where` to find the valid row indexes:

```
idx, = np.where((rand_arr == arrlist[:,None]).all(axis=-1).any(0))
```

Comment: It appears that `(rand_arr == arrlist[:,None])` is a boolean variable, not an array.

Comment: It is not possible for that to be the case with the variables you've shown. @proton

Comment: @proton with what you provided, it is a 3-d array with shape `(2, 5, 4)`